# reactjs how to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { 
        address: {
            street:null,
            city:null,
            postalCode: null
        }
    };
}
postalCodeChange(e){
    this.setState.address.postalCode = e.target.value;
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

I'm trying to update the state, but the postalCode only. When the above code execute, I expect to get something like this

```
Object {address: Object {
           street: null,
           city: null,
           postalCode: 'some new value'
} }
```

But I got error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to update state you must use [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) method

```
const state = merge({}, this.state, {
  address: { postalCode: e.target.value }
});

this.setState(state);
```

**Note** - *`merge` it is not real function, in order to deep merge objects you can use packages like [`merge-deep`](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/merge-deep), [`assign-deep`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assign-deep)*

or you can use [`update`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) method from [`React.addons`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/addons.html), to get this method do the following steps

1. `npm i react-addons-update --save`
2. `import`(or `require`) and use it

   ```
   import update from 'react-addons-update';
   const state = update(this.state, {
     address: { 
       postalCode: { $set: e.target.value }
     }
   });     

   this.setState(state);
   ```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/37835/)

also if you use `ES2015` you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), or [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

**`Object.assign`**:

```
const state = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
   address: Object.assign({}, this.state.address, { postalCode: 1000 })
});
```

**`spread operator`**

```
const newState = {
  address: { ...state.address, postalCode: 1000 }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I saw that you are using ES6, so I'm assuming you can also use the [stage-2 object spread operator](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread).

By using that feature, you can update your state without additional plugin or lots of code.

```
this.setState({
    address: {
        ...this.state.address,
        postalCode: e.target.value
    }
});
```