# ReactJS: What is the correct way to set a state value as array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

I have an array of object that get users data using fetch API. I have tried constructor, create a function, bind it. It didn't work. I tried ComponentDidMount and setState, it returns undefined.

```
class Admin extends Component {


    componentDidMount () {

        var that = this;
        fetch('http://localhost:4500/data/users', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
         }).then(function(response) {
             return response.json();
        }).then(function(json){
             console.log(json);
             that.state = {users: json};
        });

    }

    render() {

     return (

        <SpicyDatatable
          tableKey={key}
          columns={columns}
          rows={this.state.users}
          config={customOptions}
        />
       );
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to set a state value as array and render it? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reactjs how to update state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527426/reactjs-how-to-update-state)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First initialize your state in your constructor like this

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {users : []} //initialize as array
    }
```

Then instead of `that.state = {users: json};` set your state using

```
that.setState({ users: json });
```

Comment: I don't think you want the parenthesis around the state object. It should be `this.state = {users: []}`

Comment: I get the data when I logged it.

Comment: Here is sample data:  [
{
"name": "Cars45 Test",
"email": "test@cars45.com",
"role": "Super Admin",
"date": "2-7-2017"
},
{
"name": "Jane Doe",
"email": "janedoe@test.com",
"role": "Super Admin",
"date": "2-7-2017"
}

Comment: Thanks abdul. Initialize the state in constructor works.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the React `setState()` method.

```
that.setState({ users: json });
```

Comment: @Olalekan and what does `console.log(json)` show in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You already got the answer to use `setState({ users: json })`, which is right.

As an alternative to initializing the array value like [abul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3581692/abdul) said, you could also do a conditional render, depending on the component state. I.e you can render a different component if the users aren't loaded yet.

```
render() {
   const users = this.state.users;
   return !users ?
      <p>Loading..</p> : 
      <YourComponent users={users} />;
}
```