# Getting error on React Component on Render

Tags: reactjs

As I an New to ReactJS.

What i am doing is when i type is any field State should be update in particular field -

As This is my LoginComponet and Setting small Form -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/style.css';


export class LoginCompoent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        field: {
            phone: {
                value: '',
                validations: [],
                errors: []
            },
            password: {
                value: '',
                validations: [],
                errors: []
            }
        }
    };
    this.handelChangeEvent = this.handelChangeEvent.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {

}

handelChangeEvent(event) {

    this.setState({
        field: {
            [event.target.id]: {
                'value': event.target.value
            }
        }
    });
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
        <div className="loginMainDiv" >
            <div className="">
                <input className="login_inp" placeholder="Mobile Number"
                    value={this.state.field.phone.value}
                    onChange={this.handelChangeEvent}
                    type="text" name="phone" id="phone"
                />
                <input className="login_inp" placeholder="Password"
                    value={this.state.field.password.value}
                    onChange={this.handelChangeEvent}
                    type="password" name="password" id="password"
                />
                <button className="login_btn" >Login Safely</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Expected Result - on `console.log(this.state)`;

when I type 9 in phone field -

```
      field: {
            phone: {
                value: '9',
                validations: [],
                errors: []
            },
            password: {
                value: '',
                validations: [],
                errors: []
            }
        }
```

Getting Result -

```
field: {
            phone: {
                value: '9'
            }
        }
```

I don't know why all fields are suddenly hidden when i update only phone field. ?

Because of this password is not setting in the form. ERROR - `this.state.field.password` is `undefined` ???

Comment: Your click handler is out of scope. inline `onClick` in reactjs is no different from `addEventListener`

Comment: *"I don't know why all fields are suddenly hidden when i update only phone field."* React doesn't to a deep merge, only a shallow one. I.e. `field` will have exactly the value that you pass to it in `setState`. If you to preserve existing properties of `field`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40601834/218196, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36527439/218196 and any of https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breactjs%5D+update+nested+object .

Answer (score 1):

Deep merging issues, as you set a name property to your input, this should work:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  field: {
    ...prevState.field,
    [event.target.name]: {
      'value': event.target.value
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for response, As you said i have made the changes then i am getting `ERROR- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`  on `this.setState( prevState => ( {} ) )` ?

Comment: I edit my answer. Use the name property of your input instead of id.

Comment: Your answer was useful I have upVoted :) Thank you But that error was remove by this mention Article in my answer please refer to that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994964/getting-error-on-react-component-on-render/50017338#50017338

Answer (score 0):

In your handleChangeEvent function, you are updating the value of the `field` in the state:

```
this.setState({field: {
    [event.target.id]: {
        'value': event.target.value
    }
}})
```

This will obviously overwrite the existing value of the `field`.

In your case, I would recommend using the callback function inside the `setState`. Please see the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

For example, if you want to update the value of the `phone` but also you want the value of the password to remain unchanged, You could do something like this:

```
handleChangeEvent = (event) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {field: {
                [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
                ...prevState.field
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, can you please tell what `...prevState.field` will do ? in set state

Comment: That's actually a destructuring assignment operator. You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

As I have tried all the Above answers but facing the error.

> **ERROR- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null on this.setState( prevState => ( {} ) )**.

The Problem was - the reference of event are not maintain in async call that's why `event.target` is becoming `null` and getting above Error.

I got the concept of  `event.persist()` which helps to maintain all the references of the event and make the Wrapper to the browser event with async calls.

You can go to this [Article](http://duncanleung.com/fixing-react-warnings-synthetic-events-in-setstate/) Reference